# Fill an ArrayList from another class inside same package

Tags: java, class, arraylist, netbeans

I'm learning java and I spent a week just trying to do what I'm going to explain you..

I have a main class with a switch/case which will call other classes.
Also, have Car.java with the following code:

```
public class Car {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int serie;
    private double price;

    Car() {  
    }

    public Car(int id, String name, int serie, double price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.serie = serie;
        this.price= price;
    }
}
```

And some classes like "setName.java" and "setSerieAndPrice":

```
public class setIdAndName {

    public static void sName(){
        //Car c = new Car();??

        System.out.println("Insert an ID: ");
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int readId=read.nextInt();
        int idOk=readId;


        System.out.println("Write a name: ");
        Scanner read2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String readName=read2.next();
        String nameOk=readName;

        //HERE IF WHERE I HAVE THE PROBLEM - HOW CAN I SET THE ID AND THE NAME TO THE ARRAYLIST CAR
        c.setId(idOk);
        c.setName(nameOk);
        System.out.println("ID set: ");
        System.out.println(c.getId());
    }
}
```

So.. my questions are:
- Where should I declare my ArrayListt=new ArrayList<>(); ? In the main or in Car.java?
- After declaring the ArrayList, how can I access to it from setIdAndName.java class?

I hope you can help me..
Thanks in advance, much appreciated!

Comment: Note that `setIdAndName` would rather be a method name than  a class name .

Comment: [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 0):

how you do it its your call.

1) you can either define that static in main class and directly call

```
Main.arraylist.add(obj)
```

2) Objects are passed by reference so you can define a method in every class that accept ArrayList as parameter and can add items in it from inside that method.

since its pass by reference it will be changing in the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: You can declare your list anywhere :) It depends on how you use it. You will learn it from your experience.

Question 2: There are many ways to access it. Also it depends on your later use of the list. Some simple usages for you:

1. Pass the list to the method to scan car info. Something like this:

   ```
   public static void sName(ArrayList <Car> theList){
       // input car info to Car c;
       theList.add(c);
   }
   ```
2. You can access list directly. Like this: Main.theList.add(...); theList must be declared in Main class (Main.java file).

   ```
   public static void sName(){
       // input car info to Car c;
       Main.theList.add(c); // this list should be declared: static public ArrayList <Car> theList=new ArrayList<>();
   }
   ```

And I want to show you another solution to your "task" :)

Change your setIdAndName class like this:

```
    public class setIdAndName {
        public static Car sName(){
            Car c = new Car();

            ...

            c.setId(idOk);
            c.setName(nameOk);
            return c;
        }
    }
```

And change your main function to like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <Car> theList = new ArrayList <> ();
        theList.add(setIdAndName.sName ()); // 1st car
        theList.add(setIdAndName.sName ()); // 2nd car
        // ...
    }
```

I hope it will help you. Good learning :)